# _UnhandledInput method not working as I expect

Tags: c#, godot

I'm new learner of Godot Mono and I couldn't understand why `_UnhandledInput` method does not work. I don't get any error or warnings either.

```cs
using Godot;
using System;

public class GameScene : Node2D
{
    PackedScene towerPackedScene;

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        towerPackedScene = (PackedScene)GD.Load("res://Tower.tscn");
    }

    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
                    
        
    }

    public override void _UnhandledInput(InputEvent @event)
    {
        if (@event is InputEventMouseButton mouseButton)
        {
            GD.Print("clicked"); // does not show message on output
            KinematicBody2D tower = (KinematicBody2D)towerPackedScene.Instance();
            tower.Position = mouseButton.Position;
            this.AddChild(tower);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the input is not unhandled. In other words, some other node is taking the input (for example with `_input`).

You are looking for a mouse event. Is there some Control taking the mouse input? Be aware that `Control`s will take mouse input before other nodes, even if they are behind them. You need to set their `mouse_filter` to Ignore.

A common gotcha is using a `ColorRect` or `TextureRect` for background, and leave it with `mouse_filter` set to Stop (which is the default), and then being unable to get input.

See [Using InputEvent](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html)

Comment: Yes, it's because of TextureRect that is child of GameScene. I set the Mouse filter as Ignore and the _unhandledinput worked. Thank you.